# How to send a Toast from a Notification after performing an action on click in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-notifications, toast, android-context

I have an application where I send an SMS by clicking on an action button in a Notification. I want to show a Toast after the SMS was sent, but this does not work. I'm afraid it has something to do with AsyncTask and/or BroadcastReceiver.

**The workflow of sending an SMS looks like this:**

- I scan my devices contacts in an `AsyncTask` and create the `Notification` from the `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()`
- I use `NotificationCompat.Builder` for creating the `Notification`
- I add a `PendingIntent` to the `Notification` that looks like this:

  `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
                  (int) _person.getId(), i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`
- I send the SMS from a `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()`
- I try to send a Toast from there like this:

  `Toast.makeText(_context, "SMS sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

I tried to debug this but unfortunately Eclipse does not show me the variables' contents in `onReceive()`.

I also read something about "Handling compatability" for Notifications Google's developer site [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Compatibility) but I could not find a Tutorial where this is explained in more detail.

**EDIT:**

I guess it might be helpful to explain what Context is passed on through all the classes:

- In my `MainActivity` I display a `PreferenceFragment` as the main content
- In that `PreferenceFragment` I call new `MyAsyncTask(getActivity()).execute();` so that my `MainActivity` should be my `Context`
- In the constructor of `MyAsyncTask` I pass this to the class where I create the `Notification` and save it there as a member (`mContext`)
- The rest I already mentioned...

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the relevant piece of code of my `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to the `Notification`'s action:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent)
{
    String type = _intent.getStringExtra("type");
    if (type.equals("SMS"))
    {
        String phoneNumber = _intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
        String message = _context.getResources().getString(
            R.string.smstext);
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

        Toast.makeText(_context, "SMS sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Please post it if so. what is _context and where is it set?

Comment: Please elaborate on "this does not work"

Comment: Ok, the SMS gets sent, but the Toast doesn't get shown. _context is just the Context passed from onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent). (I use underscores for passed variables) I don't get an error message.

Comment: Is it normal that once you use "mContext" and once "_context" ? Are these the same. You might have the wrong context passed to your toast

Comment: mContext is a member variable that I use in the class where I create the Notification. It's best if I add some explanation about where the Context is coming from.

Comment: @Toaster I edited my original post and added some further information. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not used to using Notification so I'm not sure I got the right answer, but for what I read in the doc, it is possible that your notification should use an Intent to call your mainActivity. The function that displays the toast would then be in your Activity

Comment: @Toaster I was suspecting something like that. How exactly can I manage this. Do I just implement something like `sendToastAfterSMS()` in the `MainActivity`? And how can I call a method in an `Activity`just by `Intent`? Does it have to be static? Somehow that seems weird to me...

Comment: In what class is the onReceive() method implemented? in onReceive, can you replace the context by something like getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: @Toaster It's in `MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`. I can't call `getApplicationContext()` or `getActivity()` or something similar.

Comment: When you create MyBroadcastReceiver, pass it your mainActivity as context and store it as class variable (mContext). Then in onRecieve, instead of _context, use the context from main activity (mContext)

Comment: @Toaster I'm not "creating" it anywhere. It's a `BroadcastReceiver`. I just register it in my Manifest and pass it to the `Intent` that I pass to the `PendingIntent` that is added to the `Notification`'s action.

Comment: Oh, ok. It is also possible to instantiate a broadcast receiver in your code using new MyBraodcastReceiver(). Then, in your code also, you have to register to it in your onCreate method (using registerReciever). If you did that, you could pass your context to the braodcast reciever.

Answer (score 0):

Use a runnable. Whenever I execute commands in a thread, I set up a handler and a runnable that let me run things in the main thread when everything's finished:

```
// Declare a global handler for the class
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// Declare a runnable that will do things app-side when your thread is finished
final Runnable mMessageSent= new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.makeText(_context, "SMS sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

// Set up your thread to post the runnable when it's finished sending an SMS
private void sendMessage()
{
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // Send your SMS here
            // When finished, notify the handler so it knows to show a toast notification
            mHandler.post(mMessageSent);
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I tried basically the same before, didn't work either. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

MasterKale was close, problem is you need to send the toast from the UI thread or it won't work. I'm not sure what he thinks he was doing with that thread.

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work. I edited my post and added the `onReceive()` of my `BroadcastReceiver`. I replaced the line with the `Toast` by your code (had to change `mContext` to `_context` and had to make it `final`). But it still didn't work. This is driving me nuts. Somehow the `Context` can't be that wrong because I can access the app's `Resources`.

Comment: Try moving your logic to a Service, have your receiver start a service to send the sms and show the toast.

Comment: You mean instead of using an `AsyncTask` for scanning the contacts? Or just for the part the happens in the receiver's `onReceive()`?

Comment: Just the part that happens in onReceive, I think you are running into a lifecycle problem. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle

Comment: I moved the code to Service and call it from the `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()`. But it don't seem get the right context. I pass `getApplicationContext()` to the `Toast.makeText()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The context shouldn't matter, all that matters is that it is called for the UI thread.  Also make sure you are calling `show()` at the end...